# Android sample-chat app: Can not create chatroom (group chat)

Tags: quickblox

I have got the Android sample-chat app from the latest master release (quickblox-android-sdk-master) running but I can not create a new Chatroom from the app. If I create a chatroom by logging into my account on the quickblox site and creating a chatroom for my application then the chatroom shows up and the app works fine.

The application I am developing needs to create its own chatroom so I need the similar feature of the sample-chat app to create a new chatroom.

When I debug the sample-chat app I see that the code below is called:

```
@Override
public void onCreatedRoom(QBChatRoom room) {
    Log.d(TAG, "room was created");
    chatRoom = room;
    chatRoom.addMessageListener(this);
}
```

with a valid QBChatRoom value. But the room does not show up in the app. Also when i log into my quickblox account and look into the app, there is no chatroom created.

Please let me know if there is a problem with the sample-chat app or the android sdk or if there is something special I need to do to create a chatroom. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you create temporary chat rooms (not persistent).

Temporary room - A room that is destroyed if the last occupant exits

Try to create persistent room

Use

```
QBChatService.getInstance().createRoom(roomName, false, true, this);
```

instead of

```
QBChatService.getInstance().createRoom(roomName, false, false, this);
```

Comment: Thanks! that fixed the problem. You should update the sample chat app in your latest master release.